# Thymeleaf fill th:attr with Spring value from modelmap

Tags: javascript, spring, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I'm trying to pass a value from the modelmap (which is set in a controller) to an external Javascript file in my Thymeleaf (version 3.0.11) template but I can't get it to work. My guess is that my syntax is incorrect but I'm not able to find proper documentation on the exact issue I'm trying to solve.

So in a controller I'm storing a value in the modelmap:

```
@RequestMapping(method = GET)
public String showView(final ModelMap modelMap, final HttpServletRequest request) {
    modelMap.addAttribute(MESSAGE, "message");
    return VIEW;
}
```

Then in the `VIEW` template I'm currently using inline Javascript to set the value to later use in an external Javascript file (which currently works fine):

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    const message = /*[[${MESSAGE}]]*/ '';
</script>
```

But we want to remove all inline Javascript from the application so we need to pass this value in some other way. Our idea is to do it like this:

```
<div id="SOME_ID" th:attr="data-message=${MESSAGE}">SOME CONTENT</div>
```

Then in the external Javascript file we get the value of this attribute like:

```
var message = document.getElementById("SOME_ID").getAttribute("data-message");
```

But unfortunately this does not work, the variable is always null in this case..

It does work for other types of attributes, for example:

```
<div id="SOME_OTHER_ID" th:attr="data-url=@{/some/url}"
```

This value we can get correctly in the external Javascript like so:

```
var url = document.getElementById("SOME_OTHER_ID").getAttribute("data-url");
```

Are we using the wrong syntax? Or should we not go for this approach at all?

Comment: @andrewjames But how do I use this th:text within the th:attr then? I should not be part of the content of the div, but just be added as an extra data attribute

Comment: Can you edit your question to add in specific error messages, if something is not working? That would help - thank!

Comment: I've added some extra info, also a case with other syntax (with @{/some/url}) that seems to work fine. Thats why i think i somehow use incorrect syntax..

Comment: What is `MESSAGE` in your java? Is it `String MESSAGE = "MESSAGE"`?  Also, just so you know you can simply use `th:data-message="${...}"` no need for `th:attr` in this case.

Comment: @Metroids Yes it is a string value. I've tried both ways (th:data-message and th:attr) but in both cases the value in the JS file is null.

Comment: I want to know the value of the string. Is `MESSAGE = "MESSAGE"`?

Comment: I can't recreate the problem. The Thymeleaf syntaxes (yours and metroids's) and your JS work for me.